# sqlite and possible null value

Tags: c++, sqlite

Sqlite3 table have INT column with possible NULL values.

I add the data to the table with this code:

```
if ( ptr == NULL )
   sqlite3_bind_null(stmt, 5);
else
   sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, 5, ptr->key_session );
```

then I get back my values with the following code:

```
unsigned int key_session = (unsigned int)sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, 0);
```

So, what is about NULL? What is the best practice with NULLs in the table? how to check for NULL? or what will occur in my GET code with NULL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether `sqlite_column_type()` returns `SQLITE_NULL`.

If `0` is a valid return for nulls, you don't need to do anything special - nulls will convert to zero if an integer is requested.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this check:

```
if (sqlite3_column_type(stmt, 0) == SQLITE_NULL)
    ...
```

If the check succeeds, the value was `NULL`; otherwise, it was a non-null `int64`.